# Prevent striping new lines

Tags: php, ftp, newline

On some server's new line's are stripped out by server.

This happens when user uploads php scripts from a FTP Client and the file is encoded UTF-8.

So how can I keep UTF-8 Encoding but keeping new line's because this is causing some error's if I leave comments or not closed IF Statements with {}.

The editor I'm using is Webmatrix and Notepad++.

Comment: Prove that it's stripping newlines. Show hex dumps.

Comment: Try uploading the files in binary mode.

Comment: FTP 101: uploading in text mode mangles newlines.

Comment: Yes but those stuff is done by user's so is there any thing i can do to keep my script's not get stripped.